# Assigning the output of a for loop to a variable

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary, beautifulsoup

I am trying to assign the output of a for loop to a variable or dictionary, but as of right now i can only get it to print the first iteration of the loop and it's not even in the right format.

Here is my code:

```
result, data = mail.uid('search', None, "(FROM 'tiffany@e.tiffany.com')") # search and return uids instead
latest_email_uid = data[0].split()[-1]
result, data = mail.uid('fetch', latest_email_uid, '(RFC822)')
raw_email = data[0][1]

html = raw_email
soup = BS(html)
pretty_email = soup.prettify('utf-8')

urls={}
for x in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    urls['href'] = x

print urls
```

I would like the format of the output of this to be how this code executes, but all this odes is print out the extracted links properly:

```
result, data = mail.uid('search', None, "(FROM 'tiffany@e.tiffany.com')") # search and return uids instead
latest_email_uid = data[0].split()[-1]
result, data = mail.uid('fetch', latest_email_uid, '(RFC822)')
raw_email = data[0][1]

html = raw_email
soup = BS(html)
pretty_email = soup.prettify('utf-8')

for urls in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    print urls['href']

print urls
```

Thanks!

EDIT:

The way i would like it to print is this:

```
3D"http://elink.tiffany.com/r/YB7DL5S/32FU1/5A6EIF/QFMQOO/9SUZ8/52/h"=
3D"http://elink.tiffany.com/r/YB7DL5S/32FU1/5A6EIF/QFMQOO/N8ASK/52/h"=
3D"http://elink.tiffany.com/r/YB7DL5S/32FU1/5A6EIF/QFMQOO/DNH42/52/h"=
3D"http://elink.tiffany.com/r/YB7DL5S/32FU1/5A6EIF/QFMQOO/T2WPJ/52/h"=
3D"http://elink.tiffany.com/r/YB7DL5S/32FU1/5A6EIF/QFMQOO/PO7RQ/52/h"=
3D"http://elink.tiffany.com/r/YB7DL5S/32FU1/5A6EIF/QFMQOO/BRLMA/52/h"=
3D"http://elink.tiffany.com/r/YB7DL5S/32FU1/5A6EIF/QFMQOO/N8ASQ/52/h"=
3D"http://elink.tiffany.com/r/YB7DL5S/32FU1/5A6EIF/QFMQOO/SV4PN/52/h"=
3D"http://elink.tiffany.com/r/YB7DL5S/32FU1/5A6EIF/QFMQOO/RC53N/52/h"=
3D"http://elink.tiffany.com/r/YB7DL5S/32FU1/5A6EIF/QFMQOO/7Q3AA/52/h"=
```

with the solution below i ma getting this:

http://elink.tiffany.com/r/YB7DL5S/32FU1/5A6EIF/QFMQOO/1XF33/52/h?=' n:underline="" style='3D"text-decoratio='>click here, http://elink.tiffany.com/r/YB7DL5S/32FU1/5A6EIF/QFMQOO/6EN2U/52/h"=' target='3D"_blank"'>http://eimg.tiffany.com/mbs_tiffanyc/Standard/Logoblue.gif"' title='3D"Tiffany' wi="dth=3D147"/>, http://elink.tiffany.com/r/YB7DL5S/32FU1/5A6EIF/QFMQOO/T2WUY/52/h"=' lucida="" sans="" style='3D"text-decoration:none;' unicode="">ENGAGEMENT,

Comment: `I would like the format of the output of this to be how this code executes` I'm afraid I really don't understand this line or what your desired format is. Maybe you can show an example of the actual output you want?

Comment: the output is about 40 URLs parsed with beautifulsoup printed line by line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep assigning to a same key in the dict, that's your only mistake:

Collect and put it into a list:

```
urls=[]
for x in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    urls.append(x['href'])
print urls
```

Or into a dictionary:

```
urls={}
search = soup.find_all('a', href=True)
for x in range(len(search)):
    urls[x] = search[x]['href'] ##Result is: {0:firsturl, 1:secondurl, 2:thirdurl}
    ##and so on
```

This should work as you want it, hope this helps!

Comment: i like the list much better than the dict, but it is not parsing properly...please see my edit to my original post.  do i need to do some extra parsing in the loop?

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a dict with just one key which you overwrite for each iteration of the loop. Maybe a list makes more sense?

```
urls = []
for x in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    urls.append(x)
```

Comment: this seems to work, but it does not format the URLs as they were parsed by beautifulsoup.  with your solution i get a a='3DYB7DL5S&amp;b=3DW7482&amp;c=3D9YZVAZR&amp;d=3DEDMP3B&amp;e=3D1"' color:="" href='3D"http://elink.tiffany.com/r/YB7DL5S/32FU1/5A6EIF/QFMQOO/1XF33/52/h?=' n:underline="" style='3D"text-decoratio='><font color='3D"#333333"' face='3D"arial"' size='3D"1"'>click here</font></a>,  where orignally i was getting this 3D"http://elink.tiffany.com/r/YB7DL5S/32FU1/5A6EIF/QFMQOO/BRLMA/52/h"=